# How to read and understand the underlying mathematical concept about Data Programing

Tags: optimization, research

I was going through the official paper << [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07723.pdf>>](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07723.pdf%3E%3E) `Data Programming:Creating Large Training Sets, Quickly` and came across this two equations:

[image: Equations]

`Λ=(Λ1,…,Λm)` are m labelling functions which labels our training data.

Here are my doubts regarding equation 1:

What does [image] in `equation1` means? And what is value of Y, is it just {-1,1} or entire true labels of data in data-set and The final value of equation 1 will be just a number, right?

How would I read this `equation 1 and 2` in mathematical way?

Also `equation 2` is compared with logistic regression loss function. But when we minimize loss function we also have true labels attached to it. But I am not able to understand what is true lables in case of `equation 2` given in the above image?

How we put `λ(x)` from equation 2 in equation 1? `x` here would be unlabelled training data-point. What does that inner summation means in `equation 2` as **y'** is already taken care in `equation 1`. Can someone elaborate more on `equation 2` on lines of data-frame with x features.

**Updated based on answer.**

I have written `equation2` based on `equation1`. Please let me know if it is correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally familiar with that paper but I think I can give you some insight. So, $\Lambda = (\Lambda_1,\dots,\Lambda_m)$ are some random variables. Each are assumed to be independent, and can have values in $\{-1,0,1\}$ or equivalently in $\{-Y,0,Y\}$. Hence, each variable have a distribution function which will look something like this:
$$
p_i(\Lambda_i) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\beta_i\alpha_i & \text{if $\Lambda_i = Y$} \\
\beta_i(1-\alpha_i) & \text{if $\Lambda_i = -Y$}\\
(1-\beta_i)  & \text{if $\Lambda_i = 0$}\\
\end{array}\right. 
$$
with parameters $\alpha_i,\beta_i$. Note that $\beta_i\alpha_i + \beta_i(1-\alpha_i)  + (1-\beta_i) = 1$ so it is a true probability distribution. Now, note that $p_i(\Lambda_i) $ can be written compactly using the **indicator function**:
$$
\mathbf{1}_{\{p(x)\}} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{if $p(x)$ is true} \\
0 & \text{if $p(x)$ is false}\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
for some predicate $p(x)$ (which might state something like "x=4"). Using this function, we can write:
$$
p_i(\Lambda_i) = \beta_i\alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\Lambda_i=Y\}} + \beta_i(1-\alpha_i)\mathbf{1}_{\{\Lambda_i=-Y\}} + (1-\beta_i)\mathbf{1}_{\{\Lambda_i=0\}}
$$
Now, we can look at the joint probability distribution of the whole $\Lambda=(\Lambda_1,\dots,\Lambda_m)$. Since all $\Lambda_i$ are independent, then the PDF of $\Lambda$ will be the multiplication of all $p_i(\Lambda_i)$.

Then, we want to take a look at the joint probability distribution of both $\Lambda$ and $Y$. Note that $Y$ can only take values in $\{-1,1\}$ with equal probability, so $1/2$ for each. When we combine these, the joint probability density $(\Lambda,Y)$ is $\mu_{\alpha,\beta}(\Lambda,Y)$ as in equation (1).

Finally, by obtaining the maximum of the log-likelihood as in equation 2 (obtaining the "best" $(\alpha,\beta)$), you obtain a probability distribution from which you can sample data that "look like" data in the training dataset, with generated predicted classes $Y$.

So, answering to your questions:

**What does $\mathbf{1}_{\{\Lambda_i=Y\}}$ in equation 1 means?** Its the indicator function used to write the PDF of $\Lambda$ more compactly.

**What is value of Y, is it just {-1,1} or entire true labels of data in data-set?** Its the unknown predicted class. At this point, is neither fixed nor given in a dataset. It is a random variable which when sampling from $\mu_{\alpha,\beta}$ you obtain a concrete value: this is precisely what a generative algorithm is, you "learn" a probability distribution from data, and then sample from it.

**The final value of equation 1 will be just a number, right?** Its the joint probability function of $(\Lambda,Y)$, when $\Lambda,Y$ are not fixed, but random variables.

**But I am not able to understand what is true labels in case of equation 2 given in the above image?**
The data from where you are learning is contained in the dataset $S$. In (2) you replace the random variables $\Lambda$ with concrete values $\lambda(x)$ obtained from all points $x\in S$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you talk more about equation 2.? I have update my question above.

Comment: Well, let me see if I understood your questions correctly. Take the example 3.1 in the paper. $\lambda(x)$ would be to evaluate the heuristics in fig 1.a) for all points $x$ in the dataset. Eq (2) says something like: "maximize the probability of (\Lambda,Y) given that we know the values of $\lambda(x)$ for many $x\in S$". Now, now that $Y$ is a random variable in (1), but we don't want (2) to be random, since we are going to input that into a gradient descent. Hence, in (2) we have little "y", as the concrete values that $Y$ can take, and you sum over all those.

Comment: I'm no expert either and haven't read the whole paper. However, the reasoning is very similar as other generative techniques such as variational autoencoders which I am more familiarized. This procedure of setting up a probability density function parameterized by some $(\alpha,\beta)$, and then learning those parameters from data by maximizing the log likelihood is a known technique used all over this field. You may want to take a look at here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf is for VAEs but describes a very similar procedure, and is more fundamental. So you may want to start here.

Comment: I have written equation2 as you suggested. Please see if it is correct?

Comment: Well, I don't think its correct. I don't know how you obtained that expression, but you can't interchange the summation and product symbols like that. In general I would have expected other cross terms, and the term with $\{\Lambda_i = 0\}$ shouldn't dissapear. Morever, the symbols $\mathbf{1}_{\{\Lambda_i=0\}}$ should be replaced with $\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda_i(x)=0\}}$.

Comment: You can expand it as:
$$
\text{argmax}_{\alpha,\beta} \sum_{x\in S}\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^m\left(\beta_i\alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda_i(x)=1\}} + \beta_i(1-\alpha_i)\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda_i(x)=-1\}} + (1-\beta_i)\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda_i(x)=0\}}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^m\left(\beta_i\alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda_i(x)=-1\}} + \beta_i(1-\alpha_i)\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda_i(x)=1\}} + (1-\beta_i)\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda_i(x)=0\}}\right)\right)
$$

But, that's the most you could do.